# Save CheckedListBox checked items

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, savefiledialog, checkedlistbox

How can I Save CheckedListBox (only) checked items with Savefiledialog?

If I use simple listbox then I use it:

```
   If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Using writer = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
                For Each o As Object In clb.Items
                    writer.WriteLine(o)
                Next
            End Using
        End If
```

But,now I want to use checkedlistbox.

Comment: what are you trying to save?  the item text?  Have you considered My.Settings?

Comment: checkedlistbox with items to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I Save CheckedListBox (only) **checked** items with
>   Savefiledialog?

Change:

```
For Each o As Object In clb.Items
```

To:

```
For Each o As Object In clb.CheckedItems
```

Comment: I got this error: Error 1 'CheckedItems' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'.